how to model gate oxide in transiesta?
The gate oxide is located between the gate electrode and the channel of semiconductor material, acting as an insulating layer to prevent current from flowing directly from the gate into the semiconductor. This ensures that the gate's control of the channel is achieved through an electric field rather than current.
Many articles mentioned that when using Transiesta to simulate field effect transistors, they used a certain thickness of SiO2 layer as the gate oxide layer, but I did not find the relevant settings in the manual.
how to model gate oxide in transiesta?
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

The accepted answer is not, strictly, correct. Siesta (and thereby TranSiesta) enables charge distributions acting as gates.
So, while you could add the full SiO2 layers in a transiesta calculation, it typically is too heavy.
Instead one can use the charge distribution method to put in charges somewhere. This will then act as a gate that induces an electric field towards the device region.
There are several questions on this site regarding this implementation, e.g. Gate potential wiith siesta/transiesta
The basic principle is to specify some region of space where there is an accummulated charge, which induces the opposite charge in the device.
So something like this:
%block Geometry.Charge
plane
1. # The charge on the geometry
delta # type of geometry distribution
1.0 1.0 1.0 Ang # An intersection point, in the plane
0. 0. 0.2     # The normal vector to the plane
%endblock

This would create a plane at $z=1 Ang$ with a charge distribution of 1, spanning the entire unit-cell.
If one has e.g. a 2D graphene structure at $z=10 Ang$ this would result in a plate-capacitor setup. This method has been studied and implemented in 1.
Agreed, that the above method does not change the permittivity of the vacuum region in between.

Thank you very much, Sir!
